# Why I can't load images with django?

Tags: python, django-templates

I'm making a website using django (3.0.7) and when I want to load an image from the web using its link it just doesn't work.

```
<img
src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.inquirer.com%2Fphoto%2Finq%2Fbest-pictures-of-philadelphia-2019-20191219.html&psig=AOvVaw3AKV5myQtFpQ-VTJMoW9Yb&ust=1592904761976000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCIjpj7-PleoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD">
```

Every thing works just fine except for this. Please help me!!

Comment: Try to enter the url into your browser and see what happens...

Comment: have you tried with another image? It seems like this url redirects to theinquirer, and not to an image hosted on the web.

Comment: Because your link its from HTML page not a image.